# How can I set options with variables in GD::Graph?

Tags: perl, gd-graph

I am creating graphs using `GD::Graph::lines`. For option set, I have to write fixed values for options e.g. `x_label => "label"` as per below code:

```
my $mygraph = GD::Graph::lines->new($x, $y);
$mygraph->set(
    x_label     => 'label1',
    y_label     => 'label2',
    title       => 'title',

    line_types  => [1, 1, 1, 1],
    line_width  => 2,
)
```

Is there any method to make these options to read variable like `$x` and `$y` are input variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace with a variable like this:

```
my $mygraph = GD::Graph::lines->new($x, $y);
$mygraph->set(
    x_label     => $label_x,
    y_label     => $label_y,
    title       => $title,

    line_types  => [1, 1, 1, 1],
    line_width  => 2,
)
```